# How to run function in loop with changing inputs

Tags: python, algorithm, while-loop

After the end of the first round of my program (Collatz function), I want my program to continue to calculate from the previous result.

I wrote a program with the possibility of one iteration, which starts from the input:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0: #parity conditions value
        return number // 2
    if number % 2 == 1: #parity oddness value
        return 3 * number + 1

result = 5    
while True:
    print ('Type your number')
    result = int(input())
    print (collatz(result))
```

Comment: Instead of printing the result of `collatz()`, store it in a variable. Then you can print it out _and_ pass it as the argument for the next call to `collatz()`. Try it out.

Comment: you can add a variable=Flag and go through the loops as inner loop, when the criteria is met say Flag=1 then jump to outer loop.

Comment: @Synochek Did my post is what you meant?

Comment: @DavidWinder Yes, it is real what i wandet! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Synochek If my post helped you please mark it as accepted (the "v" mark at the left of the post) so other may use it

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python Collatz iteration", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to re-run the function over and over again with the last ran result - store the return value in variable and call the function with it.

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0: #parity conditions value
        return number // 2
    if number % 2 == 1: #parity oddness value
        return 3 * number + 1

print ('Type your number')
result = int(input()) #first time the input will come from the user
while True:
    result = collatz(result) #calculate new result
    print (result)
    #if you want to add break out of the loop put it here
```